# Mbasic Input value

Tags: basic

Using MBasic on an old  CP/M  trying to get a simple input which seems to not be working

```
10 INPUT "Your Name:", NAME$
20 PRINT "Hello, " + NAME$ + ","
```

I am just working threw this, never used it before. Its a program for an old CPM 
When i Run this i get 
Syntax error in 10

Comment: Have you tried using a semicolon instead of a comma after the string? Perhaps you also need to swap the "+" characters for semicolons in the PRINT statement. It is a stab in the dark as I have no possibility to test my suggestion, but hope that helps.

Comment: I will give it a try :D   not sure if i tried that or not as i have tried alot of different symbols.., but if i take out the INPUT line, it will run so i think + is ok

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is LINE INPUT with a semi-colon, i.e.

```
10 LINE INPUT "Your name:"; NAME$
```

[Microsoft BASIC Compiler 1980](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/microsoft/cpm/Microsoft_BASIC_Compiler_1980.pdf)